# Prove that a real-valued function on an open interval is continuous at any point where its derivative exists.

Tags: limits

Prove that a real-valued function $f$ on an open interval $I$ is continuous at any point where its derivative exists, i.e.
where
$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
exists. What is the converse of this assertion? Prove that the converse is not true.

Please give me some clue how to prove this.

Comment: What have you tried, or what are you thinking about? Do you know what the converse of the assertion is?  What are the definitions of terms like continuous or limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that if $a \in I$ then $$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(a),$$ so $$\lim_{x \to a}[f(x)-f(a)]=\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\cdot (x-a)=f'(a)\cdot 0=0,$$ so $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x)=f(a)$, that is, $f$ is continuous at $x=a$.

The converse is that every continuous function at a point $x=a$ is derivable at that point.

Now, to prove the converse is not true, consider the function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=|x|$. This function is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ but is not derivable at $x=0$ (why?).

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If the derivative of $f$ exists at $a\in I$  then 
$$\lim_{x \to a} \left(f(x)-f(a)\right)=\lim_{x \to a}\left(\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\cdot (x-a)\right)=f'(a)\lim_{x \to a} (x-a)=0.$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)$$

Thus

$$lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}×{h}= lim_{h\to0} hf'(x)$$

Thus $$lim_{h\to0} f(x+h)=f(x)$$

But  $lim_{h\to0} {f(x+h)-f(x)}=0$ does not imply $lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ exists.